# Calculus: need help with if sum of a series converges or not

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The series is: $\sin(x) + \sin^3(x) + \sin^5(x) + ...$ where $x$ tends to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
I am getting two different results by two different methods.

Method $1$:
since in this case my common factor is less than $1$, I can use the infinite geometric progression sum formula which gives me the result positive infinity.

Method $2$:
If first, I take the series to be $n$ terms and use the geometric progression sum formula, it gives me $\frac00$ form. Applying L’Hôpital to it gives me the sum to be: $n\cdot(\sin(x))^{2n-2}$ where $x$ tends to $\pi/2$ and $n$ tends to infinity. This gives the sum to be $0$ as anything less than $1$ to the power $0$ tends to be $0$.

I am probably missing some assumption in one of the methods wrong leading it to be wrong but can't figure out which one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can say nothing about the limit of $n(\sin x)^{2n-2})$ when $n \to \infty$ and $x \to \frac {\pi} 2$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $0≤x<\frac{π}{2}$, $$\sin(x) <1⇒\sin^2(x)<1$$

This gives way to summation of infinite GP formula($S=\frac{a}{1-r}$,$a$=first term,$r$=common ratio), as your series can be represented as
$$\sum_1^\infty \sin^{2n-1}(x) = \sin (x) + \sin^3(x)+\sin^5(x)+...=\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\sin (x)}{\cos^2 (x)} $$

Now $$x→\frac{π}{2} \implies S=\lim_{x\to\frac{π}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=∞$$ Hence this is a divergent series.

Graphical proof:-

[image]

Your logic was correct. In the second formula too, where you took n,
$$S=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin x\frac{1-\sin^{2n}(x)}{1-\sin^2 x}$$ will ultimately give the same value of $S$.

Putting limits of x directly to S before $\lim_{n→∞}$ gives $\lim_{n→∞}( \lim_{x→\frac{π}{2}}\sin x\frac{1-\sin^{2n}(x)}{1-\sin^2 \frac{π}{2}})=\lim_{n→∞}\sin^{2n-2}\frac{π}{2}=0$

But this operation is faulty because you aren't taking the $n→∞$ part into account, and assuming $n$ is finite while solving the first limit .

Comment: This is just the method $1$ of the OP. I believe he didn’t have a problem with it. His question was rather, where exactly is the mistake in his reasoning.

Comment: "Hence this is a divergent series." Why "hence"? and what "series" are you talking about? If it is $\sum_1^\infty \sin^{2n-1}\frac\pi2$, i.e. $1+1+\dots$, the divergence is obvious and the "hence" is at best unclear.

Comment: @AnneBauval  Can you please tell me what should I use? I'm not trying to be rude or arrogant. The value doesn't converge at a single point, but it goes to +ve $\infty$. Help will be be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Denoting by $S_n(x)$ the partial sums of the series, your method 1 finds correctly
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n(x)=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin^2x}=\infty.$$
Your method 2 is wrong because $$\text{as}\quad x\to\pi/2,\quad S_n(x)\sim T_n(x):=n\sin^{2n-2}x$$
but
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n(x)\ne\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\lim_{n\to\infty}T_n(x)=
\lim_{x\to\pi/2}0=0.$$